# How to convert fasta alignment to nexus or phylip format?

Tags: sequence-alignment, format-conversion

I generated a multiple sequence alignment using mafft, but I would like to convert it to nexus or phylip format (required by a downstream software). What's the easiest way to do the conversion?

Answer (score 1):

EMBO's bioinformatic suite [EMBOSS](https://www.ebi.ac.uk/Tools/emboss/) has [seqret](http://emboss.sourceforge.net/apps/cvs/emboss/apps/seqret.html) program that can do exactly that. You can install it via conda (`conda install -c bioconda emboss`) and then the conversion to `nexus` is

```
seqret -sequence input.mafft.fasta -outseq output.mafft.nex -osformat nexus
```

Answer (score 1):

```
from Bio import AlignIO
from pathlib import Path
from Bio.AlignIO.PhylipIO import SequentialPhylipWriter
import re

file = 'input.mafft.fasta'
fileoutnex = re.sub('fasta', 'nex', file)
pathway = '/mypath/'
alignment = AlignIO.read(Path(pathway, file), 'fasta')

# write out in nexus
AlignIO.write(alignment, Path(pathway, fileoutnex), 'nexus')

# write out in relaxed phylip
fileoutphy = re.sub('fasta', 'phy', file)
with open(Path(pathway, fileoutphy), 'w') as output_handle:        
    SequentialPhylipWriter(output_handle).write_alignment(alignment, id_width=30)
```

The advantage here is you can select what phylip format you want. That is a BIG advantage, traditional phylip format is terrible, particularly with taxa ids lengths. Here relaxed phylip format is being used.

The other advantages,

- Easily parse, change, alter the taxa names;
- Phylip taxa id can be ANY length (`id_width=`);
- save it as a script;
- no need to write an outfile (ok minor);
- pipe the alignment straight into downstream stuff;
- very easy manipulate the alignment.